# How to divide large Http Response

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have Spring Boot RESTful service API. The consumers are other applications. One of the app's controller returns up to 1 000 000 strings on request.

What is the best practice of splitting such responses in Spring applications?

**Update:**
I figured out the response is needed for developer's needs and would be executed only once. So it's better to create the script for this operation. 
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Best practice called "pagination of data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example to use multi part request in spring boot: https://murygin.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/rest-web-service-file-uploads-spring-boot/

However, I would  prefer to think about your problem from an architectural point of view.Why should the rest returns such a huge response?And is it necessary to really returns all those results?  There are a few factors that might help me to give a better answer. 
This is the kind of situation when there is always a trade off.

1)The basic question is, can't you provide additional(they don't have to be mandatory, they can be optional parameters) to reduce the amount of returned results?
2)How frequent does your data change?If they don't change pretty often(let's say once a day) then you can introduce a sort of paging mechanism so you return only a segment of the result. From your side , you can introduce a caching mechanism between your business logic layer/data base and the rest client.
3)If your data are changing frequently(like you are providing list of flight prices), then you can introduce a caching layer per client ID. You can cache the results from your side and send it to the client divided into several requests. Of course you will have to add a time stamp and expiry date for each cached request or otherwise you will face memory issues.
4) This leads us to another question, where does the pain comes from?
Does the application clients complain about not being able to handle the amount of data they receive? Or do they complain from your response time of your service?Or are you having performance issue on your server side?